# SQL DELETE not work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, sql-delete

Good morning, everyone,

I have a problem with my script I can't figure out how to make a feature. I'll explain:
I'm using the outlook API I get my mails, send them to my bdd in an inbox table. I then have some buttons that allow to send my mails in other table (to do/ Urgent/Archive).
The problem is that I want to delete the inbox data when I send an email to another table.

I have a view file (I don't put it in I don't think it's useful)
A file with my AJAX request:

```js
window.onload = function(item){
      
      console.log("********************TEST_INSERT*********************");
   
   
      for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++){
          console.log("after for");
          console.log($i);
   $thisInput = document.getElementsByClassName('from_1')[$i].textContent;
   $thisSub = document.getElementsByClassName('subject_1')[$i].textContent;
   $thisRecei = document.getElementsByClassName('received_1')[$i].textContent;
   $thisPreview = document.getElementsByClassName('bodypreview_1')[$i].textContent;
   $thisBody_2 = document.getElementsByClassName('body_2')[$i].textContent;
    console.log("*********************");
    console.log($thisInput);
    console.log($thisSub);
    console.log($thisRecei);
    console.log($thisPreview);
    console.log($thisBody_2);
    console.log("*********************");
    
    
      



    console.log("**********************");
    console.log("******STOCK************");
    console.log("**********************");
    
      
//var $input = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".from_1")[0].innerHTML;
//var $sub = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".subject_1")[0].innerHTML;
//var $recei = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".received_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
//var $preview= $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".bodypreview_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
//var $body_2 = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".body_2 em")[0].innerHTML;
$.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {info: 'stock_mail_inbox', input: $thisInput, sub: $thisSub, recei: $thisRecei, preview: $thisPreview, body : $thisBody_2},
    success: function() {
        console.log("OK");
    }
});
};
 $.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {info: 'display_mail'},
    success: function(html) {
        console.log("OKok");
        
        $('#display_mail').html(html);
   
    
    }
});

}; 



function btn_a_faire(item){
   
  
   
    console.log("**********************");
    console.log("******ajax A FAIRE************");
    console.log("**********************");
var $thisInput = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".from_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisSub = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".subject_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisRecei = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".received_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisPreview = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".bodypreview_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisBody_2 = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".body_2 em")[0].innerHTML;
console.log($thisBody_2);
$.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general_2.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {info: 'insert_to_db_a_faire', input: $thisInput, sub: $thisSub, recei: $thisRecei, preview: $thisPreview, body : $thisBody_2},
    success: function() {
        console.log("OK");
    }
});

};


function btn_urgent(item){
    console.log("**********************");
    console.log("******ajax URGENT************");
    console.log("**********************");
var $thisInput = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".from_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisSub = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".subject_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisRecei = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".received_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisPreview = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".bodypreview_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisBody_2 = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".body_2 em")[0].innerHTML;
$.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general_3.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {info: 'insert_to_db', input: $thisInput, sub: $thisSub, recei: $thisRecei, preview: $thisPreview, body : $thisBody_2},
    success: function() {
        console.log("OK");
    }
});
}


function btn_archive(item){
    console.log("**********************");
    console.log("******ajax URGENT************");
    console.log("**********************");
var $thisInput = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".from_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisSub = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".subject_1")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisRecei = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".received_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisPreview = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".bodypreview_1 em")[0].innerHTML;
var $thisBody = $(item).closest(".emailBody").find(".body_2 em")[0].innerHTML;
$.ajax({url: '../../wp-content/plugins/game_plugin/process_general_4.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {info: 'insert_to_db_archive', input: $thisInput, sub: $thisSub, recei: $thisRecei, preview: $thisPreview, body : $thisBody_2},
    success: function() {
        console.log("OK");
    }
});
}
```

And I have 4 files that process INSERTs in my bdd (proccess_general. php/proccess_general_2...):

Proccess_general.php:

```html
 $info = $_POST['info'];
$thisInput= $_POST['input'];
$thisRecei= $_POST['recei'];
$thisSub= $_POST['sub'];
$thisPreview= $_POST['preview'];
$thisBody= $_POST['body'];
 stock_mail_inbox($thisInput, $thisSub, $thisRecei, $thisPreview, $thisBody);
  function stock_mail_inbox($thisInput, $thisSub, $thisRecei, $thisPreview, $thisBody){

  
 
     
global $wpdb;

         $wpdb->insert(
                    'inbox', //table name
                    array(
                'id' => '',
                'from_mail' => $thisInput,
                'subject'  =>$thisSub,
                'recei' => $thisRecei,
                'preview' =>$thisPreview,
                'body'  => $thisBody,
                
                    ), //columns
                    array(
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                    )
            );

     
  }
```

proccess_general_2.php:

```html
$info = $_POST['info'];
$thisInput= $_POST['input'];
$thisRecei= $_POST['recei'];
$thisSub= $_POST['sub'];
$thisPreview= $_POST['preview'];
$thisBody= $_POST['body'];
 insert_to_db_a_faire($thisInput, $thisSub, $thisRecei, $thisPreview, $thisBody);
  function insert_to_db_a_faire($thisInput, $thisSub, $thisRecei, $thisPreview, $thisBody){

  
 
     
global $wpdb;

         $wpdb->insert(
                    'a_faire', //table name
                    array(
                'id' => '',
                'from_mail' => $thisInput,
                'subject'  =>$thisSub,
                'recei' => $thisRecei,
                'preview' =>$thisPreview,
                'body'  => $thisBody,
                
                    ), //columns
                    array(
                '%d',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                '%s',
                    )
            );

    $wpdb->prepare('DELETE FROM `inbox` WHERE recei = $thisRecei');
  }
```

In proccess_general_2 I added a DELETE but it doesn't work. When I test my request in phpmyadmin it works but once in my code nothing works.
I hope to have been clear, I remain available if necessary.
Thank you all for a great day.

Comment: Check sql errors  / php logs, might be an error

Comment: To my knowledge of wpdb, ->prepare doesn't actually execute the query, you need to do a ->query after preparing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like `execute( )` after preparing. Try this (or find the equivalent, according to what tools you use)

```
$wpdb->prepare('DELETE FROM `inbox` WHERE recei = $thisRecei');
$wpdb->execute();
```